# Why only a handful of distinct mathematical constants appears in most applications?

Tags: soft-question, constants

> Is there some theoretical reasoning behind the fact that the same numbers ($\pi$, $e$, $\gamma$, etc) appear again and again in every application in every field of Mathematics?

Most people just accept that fact and enjoy it, but I think this is a field of study in itself, and could be a focus of rigorous theoretical work, not only by the number theorists, but every mathematician.

There is an infinite amount of real numbers, most of them are uncomputable (we can't use these), but even among the computable numbers we regularly use no more than a hundred.

> Or maybe there are many more equally important mathematical constants, but we have not invented the relevant areas of mathematics to apply them? Will we be able to do it? Maybe some alien civilization uses a completely different set of constants in their mathematics? What do you think?

There is a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/854400/269624) here, but this question is different, besides there was no satisfactory answer to that one.

**Edit**

And I do not include simple rational numbers here (but I do include the numbers that are not proven to be either way).

Comment: What about $\zeta(3)$, what about the Feigenbaum constant, what about many others? Your observation *may* in parts be a selection artefact.

Comment: Other numbers, such as 2, appear even more often, but we don't notice it because they already have convenient names. A friend of mine, during college, was on a crusade to name the number 2 after himself, imagining things like "We now multiply by Smallson's constant to double the result..." He though this might lead to a large citation count. :) [Name changed to protect the naive.]]

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, I did not mean there are only three. I said 'no more than a hundred'

Comment: Unless the universe is more strange than we think, geometry will be the same anywhere, so aliens will know about $\pi$. The same probably hold for all the basic constants, like $e$ or $\phi$ or $\sqrt{2}$ because they appear in elementary mathematical problems. While it is not inconceivable higher mathematics can have pursued different paths, I think that some building blocks of elementary mathematics are essentially unavoidable.

Comment: Then again, the constants you listed are more common then mine. Maybe this is like the Big Law of Small Numbers. $\pi$ and $e$ are prominent for "glueing" some relatively simple concepts together (area of a circle and zeroes of solutions of $y''+y=0$). Once we have another interesting concept, such as $\zeta(2)$, it is either related to other simple concepts by a Big Law of Simple Concepts (and we see that $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}6$ can be expressed with known constants) or we might've turned it into another constant (because its simplicity of concept implies that it will occur in other places).

Comment: I think everybody marvels at this at some point, and I don't think there's a good explanation of why the same few constants come up so often and only those.  C'est la vie.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/281848/269624) is a related question, actually almosth the same one. Again, no new answers